# Combining nginx location directives for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, server, webserver

Is it possible to combine those nginx location directives?

```
location = /wp-config.php {
    deny all;
}

location = /readme.html {
    deny all;
}
```

I tried it with `location ~ ^/(readme\.html|wp-config\.php)` or `location ~ ^/(readme.html|wp-config.php)` but it didn't work. If I use one of the directives from the last sentence only readme.html returns 403.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing location blocks have the **highest precedence** and are unambiguous.

The regular expression location block you wish to replace them with, may be technically correct, but may also have a lower precedence relative to other location blocks within your configuration file.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Even if i place it at the topmost position of the config file it doesn't work. Keep continue keeping it as two different directives. Anyway, thanks a lot!